# Git: Getting a 'patch does not apply' error on git checkout/reset -p

Tags: git

I am trying to use git's add/checkout/reset in patch mode for the first time.
I created a simple html file to test them:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Next, I am adding two lines inside the body tag:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

Now, I want for example to discard (checkout) the second line, so I am entering manual hunk edit mode, with 'git checkout -p', and using the 'e' option.
The diff is showing this:

```
@@ -4,6 +4,7 @@
   <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
-  
+  <h1>Heading</h1>
+  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I am deleting the + line, and using a space in its place as per the instructions below, but no matter what I try, I always get the 'patch does not apply' error.
I tried every combination of removing, commenting, indenting, changing the chunk header metadata to no avail.

What is the correct procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add-addedcontent

To remove `+` lines you just remove them completely, not replacing with a space.

To remove `-` lines you replace `-` with a space.